# Creating an Object in AWS S3 using Go Language

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

i want to create an object (file) in my s3 bucket using Go Language, i've read the API Reference and search it on google but all of them just uploading the file, no one using the method create a new object and fill it body with base64 encoded (for image), if someone can help me with this? i've done it with PHP but now im using Go Language

Comment: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/aws/aws-sdk-go.v1/service/s3#example-S3-PutObject

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mkopriva and the link, it really help me, should be flag as the answer but i dont know how, sorry, once again thank you